# Count distinct actors an actor appeared with

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a table:

| Movie | Actor | Supporting_actor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | A1 | A2 |
| M2 | A1 | A3 |
| M3 | A2 | A4 |
| M4 | A4 | A5 |
| M4 | A4 | A6 |

Calculate the total distinct actors an actor appeared with (either as an actor or a supporting actor). The result should appear like so:

| Actor | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A3 | 1 |
| A4 | 3 |
| A5 | 1 |
| A6 | 1 |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! This looks like homework which is not off-topic. What **is** off-topic is not making an effort. What have you tried? Are you really using both PostgreSQL **and** MySQL? MySQL 5.5 is EoL!

Comment: UNION, GROUP BY, COUNT().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine `Actor` and `Supporting_actor` into one column then apply an outer query doing the count.

Try:

```
select actor,
       count(actor) as actor_count
FROM ( 
      SELECT actor 
      FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN actor > supporting_actor THEN actor ELSE supporting_actor end as actor, 
                             CASE WHEN actor > supporting_actor THEN supporting_actor ELSE actor END as supporting_actor
             FROM test
           ) as act
    UNION ALL
      SELECT supporting_actor 
      FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN actor > supporting_actor THEN actor ELSE supporting_actor end as actor, 
                             CASE WHEN actor > supporting_actor THEN supporting_actor ELSE actor END as supporting_actor
             FROM test
           ) as sup_act
     ) as tbl
group by  actor
order by actor asc;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a3ee715fbb0399f80dd0f9182e62fa0)

*Note*. Do not use `UNION` because `UNION` will removes duplicate rows records.

This can be done using LEAST and GREATEST instead of the case expression .

**EDIT**. A simplified solution suggested by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)

```
select actor,
       count(distinct supporting_actor) as actor_count 
from (  select actor, 
               supporting_actor        
        from test 
    union          
        select supporting_actor, 
               actor         
        from test 
    ) as tbl  
group by actor  
order by actor asc ;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f00e9ab21256a7cba1ed66d3bd6263bc)

Comment: Oh, I looked at your answer again. It really works correctly. A bit confusing logic but 100% correct.